# Parse date to store in mysql DATETIME from php

Tags: php, mysql, parsing, datetime

I've got a date in `DD.MM.YYYY h:mm a` format, how could i parse it in php or laravel to store it in a datetime field in mysql database?

Here's the date i want to parse: `29.08.2015 11:00 pm`

I tried to parse to parse it like this:

`date_create_from_format('DD.MM.YYYY h:mm a','29.08.2015 11:00 pm');`

But it didn't work, it returns false...

Comment: probably because you should investigate yourself before posting a question, and if you had done so, you would have found a thousand links that would help you already. if you then has a specific problem with your code, you could come back here (but also then, search for an answer to that problem first)

Comment: Always, If you find any answer solved your question, mark it as correct answer. It will be helpful for those who search for the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$date = date_create_from_format('j.m.Y h:i a','29.08.2015 11:00 pm');
echo $date->format('Y-m-j H:i:s');
```

Outputs 2015-08-29 23:00:00

Answer (score 1):

new DateTime(string date) converts a string to a date object without caring the format. You can pass '29-8-2015','29 Aug 2015'.. etc as $datestring. No need to define the format of input.

```
$datestring='29.08.2015 11:00 pm';      //defined date as string
$datetime = new DateTime($datestring);      //create datetime of defined date
$datetime = $datetime->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');   //reformat to the format we need
```